# calculating the potential energy of a conservative force can't get the same answer

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, classical-mechanics

Hi i was wondering if anyone could show me how to calculate the potential energy of the conservative force $$F=(-x,2yz,y^2)$$ i know that the correct answer is $U=\frac{1}{2}x^2-y^2z$  i know that $-\nabla U=F$ $\implies U=-\int_0^rF.dr$ so $$U=-\int_0^{(X,Y,Z)}-xdx-\int_0^{(X,Y,Z)}2yzdy-\int_0^{(X,Y,Z)}y^2dz$$ clearly then from this $$U=\frac{1}{2}x^2-y^2z-y^2z\ne \frac{1}{2}x^2-y^2z$$ i dont understand how i'm going wrong if someone could tell me that would be great, Thanks.

New approach 
$$U(\vec{r})=-\int_0^\vec{r}\vec{F}(\vec{r}').d\vec{r'}$$ so let $\vec{r'}=\vec{r}\lambda$ $\implies d\vec{r'}=d\lambda\vec{r}$ so $$U(\vec{r})=-\int_0^1F_x(\vec{r}\lambda)xd\lambda-\int_0^1F_y(\vec{r}\lambda)yd\lambda-\int_0^1F_z(\vec{r}\lambda)zd\lambda$$ $$=-\int_0^1-x^2\lambda d\lambda-\int_0^12\lambda ^2zy^2d\lambda-\int_0^1y^2\lambda^2d\lambda$$ $$=\frac{1}{2}x^2-\frac{2}{3}y^2z-\frac{1}{3}y^2z$$$$=\frac{1}{2}x^2-y^2z$$

Comment: You have to actually do the line integrals by parametrizing a particular path!! These are not just random antiderivatives.

Comment: You might find the latter half of [my lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ngQcfmYT4a4&index=89&list=PL5I-Eyk8l9FHdJUd9UujGcvumjCFPHbrd) of help, although some of the notation is probably unusual for you.

Comment: i updated my attempt could you tell me if it is correct, i know the answers are the same but i don't have any constant functions, thought it would be easier to do it this way.

Comment: Yes, this is perfect. You took the straight-line path. You can also do something that's much closer to your original attempt by taking a line segments from $(0,0,0)$ to $(x,0,0)$, then $(x,0,0)$ to $(x,y,0)$, then $(x,y,0)$ to $(x,y,z)$ and it'll work correctly. :)

Answer (score 1):

$\nabla U = \frac {\partial U}{\partial x} ,\frac {\partial U}{\partial y}, \frac {\partial U}{\partial z}$

$U = \int \frac {\partial U}{\partial x} dx = \int \frac{\partial U}{\partial y} dy = \int \frac {\partial U}{\partial z} dz$

$\int \frac {\partial U}{\partial x} dx = \int x\ dx =  \frac 12 x^2 + f(y,z)$

Noitce I have an arbitrary function instead of a constant.

$\int \frac {\partial U}{\partial y} dy = \int -2yz\ dy = -y^2z + g(x,z)$

$ \frac 12 x^2 + f(y,z)= -y^2z + g(x,z)$

gives us some idea what these mystery fuctions must be.

$\frac 12 x^2  - y^2z  + h(z)$

$\int \frac {\partial U}{\partial z} dz = \int -y^2\ dz = -y^2z + k(x,y) = \frac 12x^2 - y^2z + h(z)\\
y^2z - \frac 12 x^2$

Comment: The last integral has to have $dz$

Comment: This is a *horrendous* method and likely to result in many errors.

Comment: If you're going to do it this way, start with $\partial f/\partial x$, integrate with respect to $x$, getting $F(x,y,z) = \int \partial f/\partial x\,dx + g(y,z)$. Differentiate that with respect to $y$ and match to find $\partial g/\partial y$. Integrate to get $F(x,y,z)= .... + h(z)$, differentiate with respect to $z$ and match to get $h'(z)$.

Comment: @TedShifrin  :D It seems a typo...

Comment: @RafaBudría: Still, separately integrating the three pieces and mixing and matching leads people to errors. I taught this stuff for 40+ years and students who went that route indubitably messed up.